# Python Stack Corruption?

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to python (but not to programming), and I can't explain the following behavior.  It appears that a variable (the list "children" in my example) from one object ("child") is getting overwritten by the value for that variable in a completely different object ("node").  To give some context, I'm trying to create a simple Node class to use in a tree structure.  The node has children and a parent (all other nodes).

I can't figure out why child.children gets the same value as node.children.  Are they somehow referencing the same data?  Why?  Code and output follows:

```
class Node:
    children = []
    parent = 0
    visited = 0
    cost = 0
    position = (0, 0)
    leaf = 0

    def __init__(self, parent, pos):
        self.parent = parent
        self.position = pos

    def addChild(self, node):
        self.children += [node]

node = Node(0, (0,0))
child = Node(node, (3,2))

node.addChild(child)

print "node: ",
print node

print "node.childen: ",
print node.children

print "child: ",
print child

print "child.children",
print child.children
```

Output:

```
node:  <__main__.Node instance at 0x414b20>
node.childen:  [<__main__.Node instance at 0x414b48>]
child:  <__main__.Node instance at 0x414b48>
child.children [<__main__.Node instance at 0x414b48>]
```

As you can see, both node.children and child.children have the same value (a list containing child) even though I only updated node.children.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `children` variable was declared as a class-level variable so it is shared amongst all instances of your `Node`s.  You need to declare it an instance variable by setting it in the initializer.

```
class Node:
    #children = [] # not here...
    parent = 0     # might want to rethink where you initialize these
    visited = 0
    cost = 0
    position = (0, 0)
    leaf = 0

    def __init__(self, parent, pos):
        self.parent = parent
        self.position = pos
        self.children = [] # ...but here

    def addChild(self, node):
        self.children += [node]
```

Comment: This is actually the same effect as the mutable default gotcha. The variable itself is not shared, but its value is a reference to something mutable. So those class level integers are safe, but because lists are mutable, appending to it modifies the original object.

Comment: @tobyodavies it **is** "shared", to the extent that it can be seen as part of the object at all. There is exactly one `Node.parent` value that is accessed by every `Node` instance, because it belongs to the class and not to individual instances. It's just that writing to `node.parent` creates a separate value that is part of the instance and hides `Node.parent` within `node` (but it can still be accessed as `child.parent`).

Comment: All of these variables should be set up within `__init__` and **not** at the class level, because they are logically part of individual instances. Python is not Java (or C++ or C#): Python follows the consistent rule that things declared directly inside the `class` block... belong to the class (and thus not to instances).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel correct --- there is exactly one object, but there are `n+1` separate references to it, one per instance of node and one for the class itself. This is most correctly described copy-by-value where the value is a reference to the object (identical to python's and java's and a number of other languages' calling conventions). My point was that the reference is copied to the instances --- `Klass.x` is not the same _variable_ as `Klass().x` as, although they could both be separate references to the same object (and by default they are).

Comment: I was trying to avoid commenting on the stylistic issues of where one "ought" to initialise what.

Comment: Feel free to comment on it, because it isn't a stylistic issue, but a logical one.

Answer (score 2):

You've made 'children' a class attribute, which means it's shared between all objects of that class.

Instead, initialise it in the **init** method of the class.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.children = []
    ...
```