# Memory corruption for custom class on uWSGI

Tags: python-3.6

During development of a new app based on Django, I noticed a memory corruption. I got two functions which use this class:

```
class ConfigMap():
    data = list()

    def add(self, entry: CusDeployPhone):
        for row in self.data:
           if row.phone_var.varid == entry.phone_var.varid:
               return self
        self.data.append(entry)
        return self

    def get(self):
        return self.data
```

Function #1

```
def gen_config_model(request, deploy_phone):
    deploy_phone_general = CusDeployPhone.objects.filter(phone_model=7)

    config_list_model = ConfigMap()

    for entry in deploy_phone:
        config_list_model.add(entry)

    for entry in deploy_phone_general:
        config_list_model.add(entry)
```

Function #2

```
def gen_config_endpoint(request):
    config_list_endpoint = ConfigMap()

    for entry in deploy_model:
        config_list_endpoint.add(entry)

    for entry in deploy_phone_general:
        config_list_endpoint.add(entry)
```

Both functions return the data in the list. I noticed that when calling the endpoint view, I also see the data when loading the model-one!

Somehow the class gets corrupted or merged with the existing one. Why?
The variable is local to the function.

I know there are issues with lists (references / pointers) but why in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved:

[Python Stack Corruption?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627628/python-stack-corruption)

> The children variable was declared as a class-level variable so it is
>   shared amongst all instances of your Nodes. You need to declare it an
>   instance variable by setting it in the initializer.

Change declaration to initializer.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.children = []
    ...
```